# Developing a Glip RingCentral web app

Tags: ringcentral, glip

I'm looking through the documentation and developer process around developing a Glip app but most of the information seems geared toward the old RingCentral apps.  For instance, in the RingCentral blog (https://medium.com/ringcentral-developers/there-and-back-again-a-developer-journey-7180e0faf5e1) I'm told that "you will be unable to make changes to your code and/or API permissions after your application has been granted public access" and I'm wondering how anybody could stop me from making changes to my own web app?  This information doesn't seem relevant anymore (admittedly it's an old post but I don't see anything newer).

So, for Glip, the process is to develop in the sandbox, then submit for public or private consumption.  What if I want to continue development after submitting a private app, is that allowed?  What about a public app?  Are there newer resources describing this kind of situation and I'm not seeing them?

Eventually I'd like to have a public app but I'd rather start out with testing on my own private data (live, not sandbox).  Then can I graduate to a public app?  The sandbox is okay but I don't think I'd want to jump right to a public app without testing it on more relevant data first.  I'm not trying to break the rules here, I would just like a better understanding of the process from a web app developer's perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are answers for the topics you mentioned:

**(1) Changing the App after Graduation**

The primary thing that cannot be changed is app permissions. This is necessary because app graduation is based on properly exercising selected APIs and when new APIs are added, the app needs to be tested again. Other things can be changed. This is for both public and private apps.

**(2) Graduation Process: Public v. Private Apps**

Private apps for your company can be automatically graduated by our automated graduation process. Public apps are reviewed by our team to ensure they are behaving properly before being graduated. You can, and we recommend, testing your app in production after graduation from sandbox, but typically our developers are fixing bugs, not adding permissions for new functionality at that point. For public apps, we also recommend you test with some customers before broadly releasing a public app.

Hope this helps. Let us know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks.  The permissions is fine.  The main issue is that a lot of our development depends on how well the app handles the larger production load, which means I'd have to potentially make significant changes after we leave the sandbox.  From your answer, it sounds like it's okay to make these changes after approval.

Comment: Hi @piisexactly3, can you contact me at john.wang@ringcentral.com . I'd like to get a bit more information about your app and the testing you need to do in production.